# Unity container view model communication

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, unity-container, viewmodel

**What i did**
I have HomeViewModel and SellsViewModel.

In the HomeViewModel, I have property "SellID"

In the constructor of SellViewModel, i am able to Resolve reference of HomeViewModel and stored it in m_objHomeViewModel variable in SellViewModel

In the XAML of SellViewModel, i have a textbox which shows "SellID", this textbox is bound to "m_objHomeViewModel.SellID"

**What i am getting doing this**
Doing this, whenever user selects difference "Sell" on HomeViewModel, automatically my SellViewModel picks it up and shows changes in SellView.

**Question**

1. As XAML textbox in SellView is bound to a property in HomeViewModel, changes are getting reflected on UI immediately
2. But i am not able catch any event (Such as property change) in SellViewModel, catching such event i want to load other values for the selected "SellID" from database.
3. I am not using Event Agreegator. If used, i can easily subscribed to event in SellViewModel published by HomeViewModel

Q1: How to do it without using Event Agreegator?

Q2: If in XAML, TextBox is bound to property m_objHomeViewModel.SellID, will it create memory leakage?

Q3: If in the HomeViewModel, i get reference to SellViewModel (Using container.resolve) and call a public property or method of SellViewModel whenever "SellID" property in HomeViewModel is modified. Is it a good programming practice? Here i think it will create tight coupling between HomeViewModel and SellViewModel

Please suggest on this...

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: If I understand your design, your SellVM will need to manually subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of your HomeVM.  If the SellId property of your HomeVM raises PropertyChanged, then your SellVM will see that and respond accordingly.

A2: Without seeing the entire application, simply databinding to a property won't cause a memory leak.  As long as the UI is displayed, the HomeVM will be in memory, but .NET does a pretty good job of recognizing when it is no longer needed and cleaning up the memory.  The answer to this is highly dependent on your overall design, but the simple act of binding the SellID from the HomeVM through the SellVM won't, on its own, cause a memory leak.

A3: This sounds a little strange - Without understanding the full architecture, it seems that the SellID should belong to the SellVM, and when the users switches SellID, the HomeVM loads the SellVM with the appropriate SellID.  This seems more OO and allows you to separate concerns.  This way everything about the "Sell" (sale?) is encapsulated in the SellVM and the HomeVM is strictly responsible for coordination (loading the correct child VMs). But this is based on what little I can gather about your overall design.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for posting comments for my questions.

A1: In one of the post of StackOverflow, i found comments like "Adding a binding between ViewModels is bad because it introduces a lot of dependencies" This is my i was thinking of Event Agreegation

A2: In one of the post of post of StackOverFlow, i found if in the XAML we bind property like "CustomerModel.SellID" instead of "SellID" it leads to Memory Leak. But I am not sure about it.

Please suggest...

Comment: Hi @user1386121.  My personal take is that relationships between VMs are not bad (when done deliberately), but I understand some people feel that way.  The truth is, even with Dependency Injection, you're still creating a dependency, it is just resolved at run-time rather than compile-time, and you can swap it out for a different implementation (if you're using interfaces).  But there's still a dependency. (continued in next comment)

Comment: A2 - I am not aware of this being an issue, and if I understand what you're describing, its a very common scenario.  Check the date on the question/answer - there were a lot of memory leaks in earlier versions of WPF that have since been fixed.  As always with memory/threading, it is very dependent on the overall design of the app, so take anything I (or anyone not looking at all your code) say with a grain of salt. I'd recommend checking out the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) to examine your specific scenario.

Comment: Hi All of you for providing your valuable comments.

Comment: @A2, Thanks for sending link for WPF Performance Suite. This is really a good to know.